# Moving between storyboards on XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have another question about iOS programming. I read through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014225-CH49-SW1) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBSegue.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014225-CH50-SW1), but for some odd reason I cannot figure out how to ctrl+drag the button to activate the switch between them.

This is the way I've set them up, with one storyboard called Main.storyboard and the second one Information.storyboard. [A link to the two pictures of the reference and the referenced storyboard](http://imgur.com/a/MiWYi)

Basically I try to control drag from the button to the reference, but it doesn't connect...

Can anyone hint at what I might be doing wrong?

Kind regards!

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: i just made a test project and i am able to ctrl drag form a UIButton to a storyboard reference, not sure why you wouldnt be able to... try ctrl drag from the viewcontrollers reference at the top (round yellow thing) to the storyboard reference and see if it lets you do that instead?

Comment: @Fonix That worked (dragging from the top), thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Storyboard reference object library. 
You can drag and drop it in One storyboard and set a segue to a button or Other object via storyboard.
Select storyboard reference object and select attribute inspector and type another storyboard name which you want to show in next scene. make sure Set its initial view controller.